# how do you repeat a process multiple times with java script

Tags: javascript

I have found the following code and I was wondering how can I repeat this code 9 times before changing the `newPage`. What i am doing right now is making 10 html documents and i change `newPage` to page2.html, page3.html ,page4.html so after the count done it changes and eventually cycles through all these html documents. I want to keep it to only 2 documents. index.html with this code and end.html. index ill perform this code 9 times then change to end.html. Can anyone help?

```
var startTime = 45;
var newPage = "page2.html";

function countDown() {
    startTime--;
    document.getElementById("counter_display").innerHTML = startTime;

    if (startTime == 0) {
        window.location = newPage;
    }
}

function gett(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    if (document.all) {
        return document.all.id;
    }
    if (document.layers) {
        return document.layers.id;
    }
    if (window.opera) {
        return window.opera.id;
    }
}

function watchNow() {
    if (gett('counter_display')) {
        setInterval(countDown, 1000);
        gett("counter_display").innerHTML = startTime;
    } else {
        setTimeout(watchNow, 50);
    }
}

document.onload = watchNow();

<p><b id="counter_display"></b></p>
<iframe frameborder="no" height="735" src="http://website.com/video.php" width="385"></iframe>
```

Comment: What you want is javascript to persist even though you've changed the page?  That's not possible.  You could load the contents of the page using ajax into another frame?

Comment: I don't think you need to use anything other than `getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

If you were loading the contents of the other pages with AJAX into the current page in a frame then you could replace the last line with:

```
document.onload = function () {
    for (var i= 1; i < 10; i++) {
       newPage = "page"+i+".html";
       watchNow();
    }
}
```

But as to how you do the first bit, I'll need more information about what the overal pages does etc.

Comment: Yes I have this code on all 10 pages. There is an iframe on this page and when the counter is don to 0 it moves on to the next page. I want to eliminate 9 of the pages and just have this one page cycle 9 times and then load end.html